# How can I put in a proper image path URL for radio button options in my Wordpress Child Theme Customizer?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been working on this for a while and even though i've searched through a lot of stackoverflow questions/answers, i haven't been able to find what i'm looking for.

My question:

I'm working on developing my first genesis wordpress child theme, particularly now the customizer. I want the user to be able to have different options, one of which is choosing from a few background patterns that I've designed for a certain div class. There are three different patterns, and I've been able to so far make three radio buttons. Here is the code:

```html
$wp_customize->add_setting('BG_Pattern', array( 'default' => '#f5ebdf',));
$wp_customize->add_control('BG_Pattern', array(
  'label'      => __('Background Pattern', 'FoxiePro'),
  'section'    => 'backgrounds',
  'settings'   => 'BG_Pattern',
  'type'       => 'radio',
  'choices'    => array(
   'tan.jpg'   => 'Tan',
   '#e6e6e6'   => 'gray',
   'teal'      => 'teal',

  ),
));
```

And the output is this, in the header.php file:

```html
<?php
$BG_Pattern = get_theme_mod('BG_Pattern');
?>
<style>
  .enews-widget {background-image: url( '<?php echo $BG_Pattern; ?>' );}
</style>
```

Where it says "tan.jpg", is where I would like to put in a url to tan.jpg src, which is in my child theme folder. However, any link I put in doesn't make the pattern appear. Inputting something like:

```
'bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/tan.jpg' => 'Tan',
```

also hasn't worked for me. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, because it's a child theme, needed to use the following:

```
get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/backgrounds/tan.jpg'   => 'Tan',
```